# How to get Position of button in selenium c#

Tags: selenium

One Video is there below that one button is there i need to automate that button wheather that button is present below that video or not any one please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

If the button is a part of the page [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) and it can be searched by Selenium you should be able to access it's [Location property](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.141.59/dotnet/src/webdriver/IWebElement.cs#L71) like:

```
System.Drawing.Point location = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//your_element_locator")).Location;
Console.WriteLine("My element location: " + location);
```

[image]

If you want to conditionally execute this or that code block depending on presence/absence of the element you can go for [FindElements() function like](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.141.59/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs#L455)

```
if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//your_element_locator")).Count > 0)
{
    // element is present
}
else
{
    //element is absent
}
```

If the button is not present in the DOM and it's a part of video - you will have to go for image recognition frameworks like [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/), [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or [SeeTest](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/TDB/SeeTestAutomation+-+Image+recognition)